# Unable to start new Rails project from within Ruby's Alpine docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have a docker image with the following `Dockerfile` based on Ruby's Alpine docker image.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine3.10

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base \
                       bash \
                       postgresql-dev;

RUN gem install rails
```

When I run `rails new .`, I don't see any error but many directories that should be generated as a result of the command are not generated. Here is what I see:

```
→ docker-compose run app rails new . --database=postgresql
       exist
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
```

However, if I build a docker image based on Ubuntu, `rails new .` generates all the directories and files as excepted.

Could I be overlooking some configuration or setup?

Answer (score 1):

Git is not installed on your docker image.
Below steps fixed the problem:

1. Add git to your DockerFile

`RUN apk add --no-cache build-base \ bash \ postgresql-dev \ git;`

2. `docker-compose build`
3. `docker-compose run app rails new . --database=postgresql`